# Display: none; unable to override. Doing its own thing?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to display the count-down on my website (localhost so i cant link it) but something very strange is happening.

[image: Screenshot w. code]

Is it the javascript that is causing the display none? because i have searched everywhere in the css file and there is no display none. In the main css file i have added display:block; on the last line of code.

I am not familiar with js at all. Can someone give me a heads up? thankyou

Comment: If you cannot find the reason, when you have access to the code of your page, how could others find it without such access? You should post sufficient code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: just so everyone knows, that is the html code above the inspect element

Comment: sorry i figured it was something common or easily fixed/ im new to coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really really want to override the inline style you can use:

```
#clock {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Sometimes this is necessary if you don't control the website, however you mentioned this is local. So best to find out whats causing it.

As others have mentioned, most likely Javascript.

Jquery will do that if you use something like `el.hide()` or `el.fadeOut()` etc.

Post your JS and someone will be able to tell you.

Comment: OMG IT DISPLAYED! I LOVE YOU SO MUCH. I can believe adding the !important fixed it lol. Also did the countdown disappear in the first place because it was set to 0 days 0 hours..etc

Comment: You should probably find the original problem instead, like Chris said.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Jquery is applying it (eg Fadeout)

Comment: what do i search for to fix it?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, look for `.hide` or `.toggle`.

Answer (score 0):

It is inline style so if it's not in the html page itself, probably it is some JavaScript that causes the display none.

Comment: what do i search for in the js files to fix it?

Comment: If you checked your html page and it's not there:
If you using JQuery : $('#clock').css('display','none') something like that

Comment: yeh 100% not on the html file, the html file screenshot is in the picture above. I dont know what is putting the code "style="display none"

Comment: If you checked your html page and it's not there:
If you using JQuery : $('#clock').css('display','none') something like that.
If it's pure javascript ___.style.display="none" where in ___ should appear object's name (but in your search you could check for .style.display="none" or .style.display='none')